# speed up the commit of the entity manager for 3000 recordes

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, derby, entitymanager

Im having 3 entities each entity with 5 members string and I want to persist 1000 records for each entity .
when I did performance testing the `entitymanager.commit()` takes about 1.1 seconds ,
I think this is too much time...
there is a way to speed up the commit of the entity manager?

I'm using Derby DB with eclipse link.

Comment: @SamiKorhonen- edited - im using eclipselink

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You gain most by enabling batching, but there are also other optimizations that you should consider. You can enable batching by setting following property for your persistence unit in persistence xml: "eclipselink.jdbc.batch-writing"="JDBC".

I recommend reading article at http://java-persistence-performance.blogspot.fi/2011/06/how-to-improve-jpa-performance-by-1825.html

Comment: Thanks Sami but i have two question 1. how should I know if its working good from my DB since Im using Derby and latter on I will use MaxDB . 2. when I use batch when actually the data is inserted to the DB I ask it because i add it to the persistance.xml and i put break point in the entitymanager commit and i don noticed of major difference when i use F6

Comment: When insertations are batched, data is inserted when the batch is executed. In JPA batch execution (just like ordinary inserts) may occur at any time between the persist and commit calls. If you for some reason need to force the execution without committing, you  should use entitymanager's flush operation. I would recommend enabling trace logging, if you suspect that inserts are not getting batched.